# type cast in c compiler

Tags: c

Consider the following example the mixed mode expression is supported:
`c = a + b*10.5` where `a` and `b` are integers and `c` is a float.
Describe how the data is typecast to its appropriate format

Comment: Is that your homework?

Comment: What do you mean by "describe"?

Comment: Is this how you will get your degree in computer science?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up the 'usual arithmetic conversions' in your text book, or in the C standard (§6.3.1.8 in C11 — ISO/IEC 9899:2011), which reads:

> #### 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions
>
> 1 Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the *common real type*. Unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>   the result, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>   and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
>
> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other
>   operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `long double`.
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other
>   operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is `double`.
>
> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other
>   operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose
>   corresponding real type is `float`.<sup>62)</sup>
>
> Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
>   following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>   the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> 2 The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be
>   represented in greater range and precision than that required by the type; the types are not
>   changed thereby.<sup>63)</sup>
>
> <sup>62)</sup> For example, addition of a `double _Complex` and a `float` entails just the conversion of the
>   `float` operand to `double` (and yields a `double _Complex` result).
>
> <sup>63)</sup> The cast and assignment operators are still required to remove extra range and precision.

And the *integer promotions* are defined in §6.3.1.1:

> #### 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers
>
> 1 Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> - No two signed integer types shall have the same rank, even if they have the same
>     representation.
> - The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer
>     type with less precision.
> - The rank of `long long int` shall be greater than the rank of `long int`, which
>     shall be greater than the rank of `int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `short
>     int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `signed char`.
> - The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
>     signed integer type, if any.
> - The rank of any standard integer type shall be greater than the rank of any extended
>     integer type with the same width.
> - The rank of `char` shall equal the rank of `signed char` and `unsigned char`.
> - The rank of `_Bool` shall be less than the rank of all other standard integer types.
> - The rank of any enumerated type shall equal the rank of the compatible integer type (see 6.7.2.2).
> - The rank of any extended signed integer type relative to another extended signed
>     integer type with the same precision is implementation-defined, but still subject to the
>     other rules for determining the integer conversion rank.
> - For all integer types `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`, if `T1` has greater rank than `T2` and `T2` has
>     greater rank than `T3`, then `T1` has greater rank than `T3`.
>
> 2 The following may be used in an expression wherever an `int` or `unsigned int` may
>   be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`)
>     whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of `int` and
>     `unsigned int`.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
>   bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned
>   int`. These are called the *integer promotions*.<sup>58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the
>   integer promotions.
>
> 3 The integer promotions preserve value including sign. As discussed earlier, whether a
>   ‘‘plain’’ `char` is treated as signed is implementation-defined.
>
> <sup>58)</sup> The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain
>   argument expressions, to the operands of the unary `+`, `-`, and `~` operators, and to both operands of the
>   shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

Comment: Draft can be found here: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n897.pdf

Comment: @Clark: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf is a more recent draft of C99 and there's a C1x draft: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf